# Using a repeater with a JSON string column

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

I have a SQL Server stored proc that returns a list of products. I'm using a `repeater` to display the data in my webpage. This all works fine and the rows are returned nicely. However, for each product I want to get a list of features, so for example:

`ProductID, Name, Features
1, T-Shirt, "Blue, Long sleeved, 100% cotton"
2, Jeans, "Blue, Denim, Stonewashed"`

Ideally, I want to make a single database call to my proc to return all the products and their features in one go. So, I'm thinking that I need the proc to return three columns (ProductID, ProductName, Features) with the features column being a JSON array.

I am very new to asp.net and even newer to JSON. I'm using c# and in the HTML page, I've been able to get the ProductName and ProductID aspects working nicely. I want it to look like this (the ul tag section is the features):

```
<div class="card-description"><%# Eval("ProductName") %><br><br>
  <ul>
    <li>Lightweight textured fabric</li> 
    <li>Rounded v-neckline</li> 
    <li>100% cotton</li>
  </ul><br><br>
  Product code: <strong><%# Eval("ProductID") %></strong>
</div>
```

My question then, is (a) is this the best way to do it, and (b) how do I deserialize the JSON on a row by row basis?

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Why not just have the stored procedure return a CSV? What justifies using JSON instead?

Comment: Please let us have a look at the table schema from where these records are coming and some code-behind source so that it can fix be accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I wouldn't have gone towards pushing the JSON data to a databound element. There could be many scenarios to achieve it and that depends how you are managing your records and how are they being processed. I will assume that you have two tables named `Products` and `Features` respectively with this schema: `Products (Id, Name)` and `Features(Id, FeatureDescription, ProductId)`

So, I would simply suggest you to query your data like this:

```
SELECT Name AS ProductName, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + FeatureDescription FROM Features WHERE Features.ProductId = Products.Id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS ProductFeatures FROM Products
```

And then you could evaluate and bind the returned `DataField (ProductFeatures)` to any of your HTML tag in the repeater where you want to display it.

If you want to customize the records, you can either use nested `Repeater` control and when the first `repeater` triggers `ItemDataBound` event you can bound the second repeater inside of it. Or you can process the returned CSV response using a Static method like below:

Markup:

```
<div><%# GetFeaturesHtml(Eval("ProductFeatures"))%></div>
```

CS:

```
public static string GetFeaturesHtml(object o)
{
    if(o == null || DBNull.Value.Equals(o))
    {
       return "";
    }
    var splittedFeatures= o.ToString().Split(',');
    var sb = new StringBuilder("<ul>");
    foreach(string feature in splittedFeatures)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("<li>{0}</li>", feature));
    }
    sb.Append("</ul>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And there other ways too, but this would be the simpler and efficient way to do it. Hope this helps.

**PS:** The code shared is not tested, and it may need some love.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for. The extraction from SQL wasn't a problem. I just wasn't sure one how to handle it in the webpage. Your solution works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @TimFoster Happy to help. Make sure to up-vote the answer if it helped.